# Django Custom UserModel gives error during password change by superuser i.e user my be deleted

Tags: python, django

hi every one when ever i click on change password link in admin panel change form it return to home page of admin and showing an info message that user

> User with ID "1/change/password" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

i created custom user model and custom admin class for registry 
like 
model.py

`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    Male        = "ML"
    Female      = "FM"
    Other       = "OT"
    genders     = ((Male,"Male"),(Female,"Female"),(Other,"Other"))
    doc    = 'DO'
    pat    = 'PA'
    types  = (
        (doc, 'Doctor'),
        (pat, 'Patient'),
            )
    User_Type= models.CharField(choices=types,max_length=2,default="PA")
    Address     = models.CharField(max_length=100 , default=None,blank=True, null=True)
    gender      = models.CharField(choices=genders,max_length=2,default="ML")
    birth_date  = models.DateField(verbose_name="DOB" ,default=timezone.now)
    picture     = models.ImageField(upload_to="user/",default="user/team1.jpg")
    twitter     = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="www.twitter.com")
    facebook    = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="www.facebook.com")
    instagram   = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="www.instagram.com")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Updated_at=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Updated" ,auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    objects=UserManager()
    def image_tag(self):
        if self.picture:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 45px; height:45px;" />' % self.picture.url)
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

`

**"admin.py"**

`

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label="Password",help_text="Raw passwords are not stored,so there is no way to see this user's password, but you can change the password using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>.")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        f = self.fields.get('user_permissions', None)
        if f is not None:
            f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')
    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    list_display = ('image_tag','username','first_name','last_name','email','is_staff','User_Type','Updated_at')
    allow_tags = False
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    ordering = ('username',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ( 'password','username','email',)}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name','last_name','Address','gender','birth_date','phone')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('User Type', {'fields': ('User_Type',)}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'birth_date', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
```

`

when i click on it [give error above mention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZE6u.png)

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found the problem by using your code. As it says in django docs. There are some fields you have to include in your Custom User in order to use the built-in django admin site. Just copy paste this code and migrate it all should be good. Btw while in production just turn on the debugging mode and share debug screen here it's much easier to track the problem.

```
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateField(default=datetime.today().date())

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name',]

    def get_short_name(self):
        return str(self.first_name)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join((str(self.first_name), str(self.last_name)))

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

If the problem persists just screenshot the django debugg screen

Comment: thanks buddy i got solution i have the path which is not suitable but one friend helped me and put one <a href="../password/">this form</a>